# Average, Maximum and Minimum assignment for C++

Tags: c++, max, average, min

My issue lies in the minimum function toward the end and the program pulls from a fill of about 25 names with 5 grades each. The average and maximum are running smoothly but I can't seem to hammer out the minimum. I managed to get it to pull a few names but then the program crashes. Can anyone help me understand what I am overlooking here? Please and thank you.

If you plug it in a compiler the min function is located between the 200-250 lines and a simple txt file is used to pull names and grades from.

```
// Headers
#include <iostream>     // cout, cin
#include <cstdlib>      // exit()
#include <string>       // strings
#include <fstream>      // file processing
#include <iomanip>      // stream manipulation
using namespace std;

// Global variables
const int MAX_STUDENTS = 25;    // We will not process more than 25 students even if the file contains more
const int MAX_GRADES = 5;       // Each student has exactly 5 grades
const string FILENAME = "NamesGrades.txt";  // The name of the file that you will read

// Function declarations
int loadStudentNamesGrades(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], string fileName, int maxStudents);
void displayAverages(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount);
void displayMax(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount);
void displayMin(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount);
string getLetterGrade(double grade);
int getLongestNameLength(string students[], int studentCount);

int main()
{
    int studentCount = 0;                   // You need one to keep up with the actual number of students
    int grades[MAX_STUDENTS][MAX_GRADES];   // You need a two dimensional arry for the grades of the students
    string students[MAX_STUDENTS];          // You need and array of strings for the student names
    char choice;                            // You need a variable to hold the choice of the user for the menu

    // Get students and grades
    studentCount = loadStudentNamesGrades(students, grades, FILENAME, MAX_STUDENTS);

    // Loop until user says to quit (Do loop suggested)
    do
    {
        // present menu and get user's choice
        cout << "\nGrade Report Program\n\n";
        cout << "\t1. Display Average Grade\n";
        cout << "\t2. Display Maximum Grade\n";
        cout << "\t3. Display Minimum Grade\n";
        cout << "\t4. Quit Program\n";
        cout << "\nEnter your choice (1-4): ";
        cin >> choice;

        // Process the choice
        switch( choice )
        {
            case '1':       // Average
                displayAverages(students, grades, studentCount);
                break;
            case '2':       // Maximum
                displayMax(students, grades, studentCount);
                break;
            case '3':       // Minimum
                displayMin(students, grades, studentCount);
                break;
            case '4':       // Quit
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid option.\n\n";

        }
        if(choice != '4' )
        {
            cout << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }

    }   while( choice != '4' );    

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

/***********************************************************
loadStudentNameGrades opens and read fileName. It will read in two strings, concatenate them, and then save
to the students array. It then reads five integers and save each to the grades array. The function will return
the actual number of student/grade combinations read
PARAM:  students is an array of strings that can hold up ot maxStudents values
        grades is a two dimensional array for holding the grades of each student
        fileName is the name of the file that will be opened and read
        maxStudents is the maximum number of students that we will read from the file
PRE:    students[] is large enough to contain up to maxStudents elements
        grades[] is large enough ot contain up to maxStudents elements
POST:   students[] contains the names of up to maxStudents
        grades[][] contains the grades for up to maxStudents
        The number of student/grade combinations actually read from the file is returned. This value can range
        between 0 <= numStudents <= maxStudents
NOTE:   students[] and grades[] are meant to be parralel arrays. students[0] and grades[0] are the same student     
************************************************************/
// Check 16:15
int loadStudentNamesGrades(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], string fileName, int maxStudents)
{
    ifstream inFile;    // input file stream
    string studentsName, letterGrade;  // Name of the student and grade character (char)
    int numStudents = 0; // number of students actually read


    // Open the file
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    if( inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < maxStudents && (inFile >> studentsName >> letterGrade); i++, numStudents++)

    {
        for( int j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++ )
        {
            inFile >> grades[i][j];
        }
        students[i] = studentsName + " " + letterGrade;
    }

    inFile.close();

    return numStudents;
}

/***********************************************************
displayAverages calculates the average of each student and displays the
students name, average, and letter grade of the average in a table
PARAM:  students[] is an array of strings that contains the names of studentCount students
        grades[] is an array of integers that contains the grades of studentCount students
        studentCount contains the value of the number of elements in the students[] and grades[] arrays
PRE:    students[] and grades[] contain values for studentCount elements
POST:   table of student names, averages, and letter grades is displayed
************************************************************/
// Check 16:15
void displayAverages(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount)
{
    double average;     // Average grades of students
    int total;          // total of all grades (accumulator)
    int maxLength = getLongestNameLength(students,studentCount);

    cout << setprecision(1) << fixed << showpoint;
    // Setup table header
    cout << "\n\nGrade Averages\n";
    cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << "Name" << setw(4) << right << "Average" << setw(6) << "Grade" << endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++ )
    {
        cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << students[i];
        total = 0;


        for( int j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++ )
        {
            total += grades [i][j];
        }
        average = (double)total / MAX_GRADES;
        cout << setw(7) << right << average << setw(6) << getLetterGrade(average) << endl;
    }       
}

/***********************************************************
displayMax calculates the maximum grade of each student and displays the
students name, maximum grade, and letter grade of the maximum grade in a table
PARAM:  students[] is an array of strings that contains the names of studentCount students
        grades[] is an array of integers that contains the grades of studentCount students
        studentCount contains the value of the number of elements in the students[] and grades[] arrays
PRE:    students[] and grades[] contain values for studentCount elements
POST:   table of student names, maximum grades, and letter grades is displayed
************************************************************/
// Check 16:15
void displayMax(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount)
{
    int maxGrade;
    int maxLength = getLongestNameLength(students,studentCount);

    cout << "\n\nGrade Maximums\n";
    cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << "Student" << setw(4) << right << "Max" << setw(6) << "Grade" << endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++ )
    {
        cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << students[i];
        maxGrade = 0;   
        for( int j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++ )
        {
            if(maxGrade < grades [i][j]) maxGrade = grades [i][j];
        }
        cout << setw(4) << right << maxGrade << setw(6) << getLetterGrade(maxGrade) << endl;
    }
}


/***********************************************************
displayMin calculates the minimum grade of each student and displays the
students name, minimum grade, and letter grade of the minimum grade in a table
PARAM:  students[] is an array of strings that contains the names of studentCount students
        grades[] is an array of integers that contains the grades of studentCount students
        studentCount contains the value of the number of elements in the students[] and grades[] arrays
PRE:    students[] and grades[] contain values for studentCount elements
POST:   table of student names, minimum grades, and letter grades is displayed
************************************************************/
/* Notes:
Program seems to pull 2 names and freeze on the third. Unsure as to why?
Assigns Leslie Carter 36C and code seems to break down afterwords. 
Issue is undetected any where else and seems to be isolated in this function.
*/

void displayMin(string students[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount)
{
    int minGrade;
    int maxLength = getLongestNameLength(students,studentCount);

    cout << "\n\nGrade Minimums\n";
    cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << "Student" << setw(4) << right << "Min" << setw(6) << "Grade" << endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++ )     // > is null result, < is result
    {
        cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << students[i];
        minGrade = 101;                                                 // Produced a result in the correct direction
        for( int j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++ )
        {
            if(minGrade > grades [i][j]) minGrade = grades [i][j];      // Produced a result in the correct direction
        }
        cout << setw(4) << right << minGrade << setw(6) << getLetterGrade(minGrade) << endl;
    }
}

/***********************************************************
getLetterGrade converts a numerical grade to a letter grade
PARAM:  grade is the numerical grade to convert. Expected range is 0 <= grade <= 100
PRE:    grade contains a value in the correct range
POST:   The corresponding letter grade of the numerical grade is returned
************************************************************/
// Check 16:15
string getLetterGrade(double grade)
{
    if(grade > 90 )
        return "A";
    else if( grade > 80)
        return "B";
    else if( grade > 70)
        return "C";
    else if( grade > 60)
        return "D";
    else if( grade > 50)
        return "F";
}

/***********************************************************
getLongestNameLength returns the length of the longest string from a list of strings
PARAM:  students[] is an array of strings that contains the name of students
        studentCount is the size of the students[] array
PRE:    students[] contains studentCount names
POST:   The length of the longest string in students[] is returned
************************************************************/
// Check 16:15
int getLongestNameLength(string students[], int studentCount)
{
    int maxLength = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
    {
        if( students[i].length() > maxLength ) maxLength = students[i].length();
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getLetterGrade` function doesn't return anything when grade is less than 50. Try to build with as many warnings turned on as possible. `-Wall` would have warned you about this mistake.

Comment: I learned something new today, thank you Pradhan for the tip, I modified the getLetterGrade function and now it works very well.